# Transform multidimensional array PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Greetings fellow friends i have the following array

```
[
    [
        "Name",
        "name1",
        "name2"
    ],
    [
        "Clean",
        "clean1",
        "clean2"
    ],
    [
        "Mixed",
        "mixed1",
        "mixed2"
    ],
    [
        "Incoming",
        "incoming1",
        "incoming2"
    ]
];
```

and i want to transform it in this form:

```
array(
            0 => array('Name'=> 'name1', 'Clean' =>'clean1', 'Mixed'=>'mixed1', 'Incoming'=>'incoming1'),
            1 => array('Name'=> 'name2', 'Clean' =>'clean2', 'Mixed'=>'mixed2', 'Incoming'=>'incoming2')
           )
```

any thoughts are welcome cuz im stacked :D

Thank in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please share your best attempt and explain where and how it differs from what you want. Also, is the number of elements in each array guaranteed to be the same?

Comment: First you need to transpose the array and then give the columns a key using the top row as the key. There are plenty of solutions for both steps here on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

According to the sample array, I represented it this way: `s[r0=>rn, r0=>rn, r0=>rn, ...], s[...], ...` for myself and came up with this code:

```php
$array = [
    [
        "Name",
        "name1",
        "name2"
    ],
    [
        "Clean",
        "clean1",
        "clean2"
    ],
    [
        "Mixed",
        "mixed1",
        "mixed2"
    ],
    [
        "Incoming",
        "incoming1",
        "incoming2"
    ]
];
$res = [];
for($s = 0; $s < count($array[0])-1; $s++){
    foreach($array as $r => $row){
        $res[$s][$row[0]] = $array[$r][$s+1];
    }
}
print_r($res);
```

Not the best solution of course, but well, you can improve it on your own — I just pointed the basic one.

**EDIT**: simplified the code.